# Node JS Fork TCP Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, tcp, fork

I have question about forking TCP client in Node JS. Here's the scenario.

1. Client will connect to the server (establish?).
2. Client will write the first message to the server.
3. Client will write the second message to the server.
4. The 'write' method will be looped infinitely with 5 seconds delay.
5. Point number 1-4 will be forked and create a new TCP connection (not using the same as before) with 8 seconds delay.

Here are my approachment so far.

```js
// tcp_client.js

const cluster = require('cluster')

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cluster.fork()
    }, 8000) // I expect this will delay between one and another fork
  }
} else {
  console.log(`Connected on ${process.pid}`)
  require('./sender').send()
}
cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
  console.log('server',`Worker %d died :( ${worker.id}`);
  cluster.fork();
})
```

```js
// sender.js

const net = require('net')
const send = () => {
  const client = new net.Socket()
  client.connect(8090, 'localhost', () => {
    const firstMessage = 'first_message'
    const secondMessage = 'second_message'
    const write = function () {
      client.write(firstMessage)
      /*
        The reason why I'm using setTimeout() is because if I write it as
        `client.write(firstMessage)
        client.write(secondMessage)`
        The second message won't be sent. Is there any better methods?
      */
      setTimeout(() => {
          client.write(secondMessage)
      }, 1);
    }

    setTimeout(write, 5000) // I expect this will loop infinitely
  })
}

module.exports = { send }
```

When I run the code the fork isn't delayed and the message won't loop. Is there any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Your cluster loop just schedules two `cluster.fork()` calls 8 seconds from now.  It doesn't do one in 8 seconds and then another 8 seconds after that.  Not sure if that's related to what you're asking.

Comment: You initially call `setTimeout(write, 5000)` from inside of the `connect` event handler, but you don't have one of those inside of the `write()` function itself so it won't repeat.

Comment: Also, it's perfectly OK to do two `client.write()` calls in a row - both will be sent.  But, TCP will probably combine them into the same packet.   TCP is a stream protocol, not a message-based protocol.  So, to delineate the difference between messages, you have to parse the stream.  For example, in this case, you could just put a `\n` at the end of each message and use that as a message delimiter when reading the TCP stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your two forks to be 8 seconds apart, you would need a varying time on the `setTimeout()`.  `setTimeout()` is not blocking so all your code was doing was scheduling two `setTimeout()`s - each for 8 seconds from now.  This will schedule one for 8 seconds and one for 16 seconds:

```
// tcp_client.js

const cluster = require('cluster')

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cluster.fork()
    }, (i + 1) * 8000);
  }
} else {
  console.log(`Connected on ${process.pid}`)
  require('./sender').send()
}
cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
  console.log('server',`Worker %d died :( ${worker.id}`);
  cluster.fork();
})
```

And, your write code isn't looping because the `setTimeout(write, 5000)` is inside the `connect` event handler, not inside the `write()` function.  So, it gets called once when the `connect` event fires and never gets called again.  If you want `write()` to repeat, then put this inside the `write()` function itself (or use `setInterval()`).

```
// sender.js

const net = require('net')
const send = () => {
  const client = new net.Socket()
  client.connect(8090, 'localhost', () => {
    const firstMessage = 'first_message'
    const secondMessage = 'second_message'
    const write = function () {
      client.write(firstMessage)

      setTimeout(() => {
          client.write(secondMessage)
      }, 1);

      setTimeout(write, 5000) // I expect this will loop infinitely
    }
    write();

  })
}

module.exports = { send }
```

Also, it's perfectly OK to do two `client.write()` calls like this in a row - both will be sent. But, TCP will probably combine them into the same packet. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message-based protocol. So, to delineate the difference between messages, you have to parse the stream upon reading. You should not rely on data arriving in exactly the same chunks in which it was sent.  It can be broken up into smaller chunks or multiple separately written chunks can be combined into the same arriving packet.  For example, in this case, you could just put a \n at the end of each message and use that as a message delimiter when reading the TCP stream so you could parse each incoming message separately, even if they were combined by TCP into the same packet.

Or you can use a message based protocol on top of TCP like webSocket that does the packing and unpacking into distinct messages for you and will deliver only a finished and separate message to you.

Comment: Just wondering why the write function aren't fired. It turns out that I haven't call it so it should be
```const write = function () {
      client.write(firstMessage)

      setTimeout(() => {
          client.write(secondMessage)
      }, 1);

      setTimeout(write, 5000) // I expect this will loop infinitely
    }
write()```
Your answer is so amazing. It works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I edited mine to include calling it the first time. I called it immediately the first time, but you can also call it with a `setTimeout()` if that's your desired. I hope you understood the stuff about TCP packets and being a stream protocol because any use of raw TCP has to build your own protocol on top of it and be able to interpret or parse that as data arrives because you never know what chunk of data you will get. The chunks you get on the receiving end may not be the same size pieces you sent on the other end. All the data will arrive and in order, but perhaps in different chunks.